# Cosine rule formula proof problem with do product, where does positive sign come from?

Tags: solution-verification

I if want to prove the cosine rule with the vector summation (such as I have mentioned in the picture) I start with the $\vec{a}+\vec{b}=\vec{c}$

$\vec{a}=\vec{c}-\vec{b}$
then
$a^2=\vec{a}.\vec{a}=(\vec{c}-\vec{b}).(\vec{c}-\vec{b})=b^2+c^2-2bcCos(A)$
which is completely correct.

[image]

If I change the vector such as this picture

[image]

I tried to write
$\vec{a}+\vec{b}=-\vec{c}$
$\vec{a}=-\vec{c}-\vec{b}$
$a^2=\vec{a}.\vec{a}=(\vec{c}+\vec{b}).(\vec{c}+\vec{b})=b^2+c^2+2bcCos(A)$

The positive sign before cosine is my problem.

Comment: The cosines of obtuse angles are negative, so you will be good to go.

Comment: Thank you Andrew for your tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The angle $\theta$ you meant from the identity $\vec u\cdot \vec v =uv\cos (\theta)$ is to be measured between the two vectors when the tail is at the same point. In the figure you have shown the angle $A$ is not what you use. You need $\pi -A$. From this, you reduct to angle and would recover the missing minus sign.

Comment: Thank you very much