# Cosine rule application to vectors, missing a sign.

Tags: trigonometry, vectors

[picture link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1Bgu.png)

This comes from a university pre-session problem list. v and w are vectors.

> $|v| = 1$, $|w| = 1$, the angle between $v$ and w is $1.7$ radians. Calculate $|4v + 2w|$.

Using the dot product and breaking brackets, we get the answer  $|4v + 2w|=\sqrt{20+16\cos(1.7)}$.

Using the cosine rule, as done here below,
$$
\begin{align}
a^2 &= b^2 + c^2 - 2bc\cos(A)\\
a^2 &= (4v)^2 + (2w)^2 -2\cdot 2\cdot 4\cos(1.7)\\
a^2 &= 16 + 4 - 16\cos(1.7)\\
&\implies a = \sqrt{20-16\cos(1.7)}
\end{align}
$$
you get the answer $|4v + 2w|=\sqrt{20-16\cos(1.7)}$, which is incorrect as it should be $+16\cos(1.7)$ inside the square root. This is despite the vectors $v$ and $w$ sharing the same tail ("the angle *between* $v$ and $w$ is 1.7"), *and* that only magnitudes are ever used.

What is wrong with the application of the cosine rule here?

Thank you.

Related question, not helpful here:
[Cosine rule formula proof problem with do product, where does positive sign come from?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3915826/cosine-rule-formula-proof-problem-with-do-product-where-does-positive-sign-come)

Comment: Draw yourself a diagram and you will see $A=\pi-1.7$, not $1.7$, because the you want to go from $-2w$ to $4v$ via $0$, not from $2w$ to $4v$ via $0$.